# Javascript read text file from current directory

Tags: javascript, html

How to read text file (text1.txt) from current directory using javascript without jquery. I tried the following code.

```
var file = "text1.txt";
var reader = new FileReader();
var result = reader.readAsText(file);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: what do you mean by current directory

Comment: The user must first "upload" the file to the page before you can select it. You can't access a file without the user consent. Or is the file on *your* server? Then you need Ajax, not FileReader.

Comment: looking at the API docs, this is an asynchronous operation. Your `result` will only be valid when loading is done. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader#readAsText%28%29

Comment: My result from the above code is undefined. Not a file that is uploaded by user. Is a text file together with my html file and javascript file in a common file directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The FileReader API is usually used to read files selected via the an `<input type="file">`. It cannot read arbitrary files. The [`readAsText` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader#readAsText()) expects to receive with a Blob or a File object, not a string containing a file name.

To read files that are siblings of the HTML document, use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). This will reliably work if you load the document over HTTP(S). If you are using a local HTML document (via a `file:` URI) then security restrictions in many browsers will prevent it from working (and you should run a local web server instead).

Answer (score 4):

***Option A, Your use-case prevents you from using an http or php server.***
You can include local content in your javascript as a variable using a script include.  If you are opening the page locally, as a file from a directory, this is the only way to include local content in the web page.

To include local content, put this above your other script tag:

```
<script src="text1.txt"></script>
```

and edit your text1.txt file so it assigns all the content to a variable:

```
gbl_text=`...contents of my text file...
...more contents...
...and so on....   
`
```

You can use a script to create this include file, for example (use the ` tick mark below the tilde ~ key):

```
echo -n "var gbl_text=\`" > text1.txt
cat your-original-file.txt >> text1.txt
echo "\`" >> text1.txt
```

Then use the gbl_text variable in your javascript as needed...

```
function dosomething()
{
  if (typeof(gbl_text)=='undefined'){
    setTimeout('dosomething()',500)  //call back until defined
  }else{
    console.log(gbl_text)
  }
}
```

***Option B, Your use-case would allow you to use the php-cli built-in server.***
If you are able to run php-cli, you can open the page on the built-in php webserver, and read and write local content with a php call.  To install and use php on linux,

```
sudo apt install php7.0-cli
#To use the php built-in webserver, run:
php -S localhost:8000 -t /path/to/your/content
```

So, instead of opening your html as a file, you would open as an http web page:

```
firefox http://localhost:8000/mypage.html
#or browser of choice
```

Now the local webpage is being served by an actual (local) http server with php support, and you can manipulate local files with it.

Here is simple example showing how to read and write to a local file using jQuery and php.  Download and include jQuery (see jQuery.com) in your html file.

Contents of dofile.php:

```
<?php 
$dowhat  = $_REQUEST['dowhat'];
  if ($dowhat=='save'){
    $myvar = $_REQUEST['myvar'];
    file_put_contents('myfile', $myvar); 
  }elseif($dowhat=='read'){
    $myvar=file_get_contents('myfile');
    echo $myvar; 
  }
?>
```

Contents of mypage.html:

```
<script src='jquery-3.2.1.js';></script>
<!--make sure the filename matches the jQuery you use-->

<script>
function savevar(){
  var myvar=document.getElementById('mytxt').value
  var path="dofile.php?dowhat=save&myvar="+myvar 
  $.get(path, function(data){
    console.log("saved ...\n"+myvar)
    alert("saved ...\n"+myvar)
  });
}

function clearbox(){
  document.getElementById('mytxt').value='reading file...'
  setTimeout('getvar()',1000)
}

function getvar(){
  var path="dofile.php?dowhat=read"
  $.get(path, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    document.getElementById('mytxt').value=data
    /*do other things with data here*/;
  });
}
</script>

<html>
Type something in the text box.<br>
Use the Read and Write buttons to verify <br>
text is saved and read back.<br> 
<input id='mytxt' value='type text here' onclick=document.getElementById('mytxt').value=''><br>
<input type='button' value='Save' onclick=savevar() ><input type='button' value='Read' onclick=clearbox() >

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me on a couple of my pages, but now I need to figure out how to make the script source a variable, which I pass to the new page through local storage.

Comment: I've rewritten the answer to clarify a couple of ways to include a local file in an html document.  If anyone knows why this was downvoted, please leave a comment and I'll try to improve the answer.  Due to security restrictions on browsers, there are only a few ways to bring in local content.  Another way could be to use Python and webkit, but I don't want to post anymore information unless someone is willing to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please distinguish 2 kinds of reading files:

- reading "from internet"  - use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) to read any kind of file
- reading "from client" - use FileReader or `<input type="file">`

Answer (score 0):

make a tiny iframe.
load the file there.
read it with iframe.innerHTML

Comment: Please describe your problem in brief with code eg.